# Sparsest cut of a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a general solution to the [sparsest cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)#Sparsest_cut) on a square grid graph? Assume the graph is undirected and with equal edge weights.

Given the regularity of the graph and I feel like a general solution should exist.

Comment: What's your definition of grid graph? E.g.: Is it a square grid? Is it finite?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph It is a finite graph. It can be rectangular as well

Comment: Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Yes, thank you. My next question: what about trivial solution, i.e. cutting the grid in half?

Comment: Ah yes ..I think thats it... It cant get better than that right ?